# Exhibit a bijective function $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ with infinitely many orbits

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

I've the following exercise:

> Give an example of a bijective function $\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z$ with infinitely many orbits.

What would be its infinite orbits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $f(n) = n $ for $n\le 0$. Lots of orbits of length 1.

Let $f(1)=2, f(2) = 1$. This is an orbit of length 2.

Let $f(3)=5, f(4) = 3, f(5) = 4$. This is an orbit of length 3.

Etc, etc.

Then $f$ is a bijection with orbits of arbitrary length.

Comment: Nice how we have answers varying in sophistication and generality :).

Comment: @Jyanluka: I need some more info. to answer your ques

Comment: One moment, for the orbit's definition, How does such a function to be an orbit...?

Comment: How do you define orbit?

Comment: On my book(Proof and Fundamentals of Bloch) it says:  Let $a \in A$. The orbit of a with respect to f, denoted O_a, is the set deﬁned by $O_a ={f^n(a) | n \in Z}$.  That is a definition of orbit..

Comment: So using $f$ above, $O_n = \{n\}$ for $n \le 0$, $O_1 = O_2 = \{1,2\}$, etc., etc.

Comment: Or as above, all i need is an example, as that of a function that swaps..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23617/discussion-between-jyanluka-and-copper-hat).

Answer (score 7):

I think you will profit from re-reading the definition of *orbit*.

After you've done that, consider $z \mapsto -z$ and prove that it constitutes an example.

Comment: *Much* better than my example. But I've left mine to indicate that you can also have infinite orbits there as well.

Comment: Nice. I could only think of complicated examples.

Comment: Of course the simplest example is the identity.

Answer (score 7):

**HINT:** Recall that there is a bijection between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb{Z\times Z}$. Can you find a bijection $f\colon\Bbb{Z\times Z\to Z\times Z}$ with infinitely many *infinite* orbits?